# Using ST monad for efficiency purposes

Tags: haskell

I have some traditional state-passing code which I need to optimize.  I've heard that if you're maintaining and updating state a lot that using the `ST` monad can help improve efficiency.  However, after looking into the `ST` stuff a bit I'm a bit unclear as to how/where the `ST` monad should be used.

A couple of approaches that come to mind:

1. Instead of passing state everywhere, pass `STRef`'s instead.  So for instance, `foo :: State -> a -> b -> (State,c)` becomes `foo :: STRef s State -> a -> b -> ST s c` and so on.
2. Keep my function signatures the same but use `ST` under the hood using `runST`.
3. Only use `ST` when updating the state in my main execution loop and escape `ST` using either `runST` or `stToIO`.

Obviously, these questions will ultimately depend on the specifics of my project but I'm wondering if there are any rule-of-thumb type guidelines that might be helpful before more detail is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only approach 1 seems to be viable, in the general case.

When `runST action` returns and delivers its result, it will deallocate all the memory which has been allocated running the `action` using `newSTRef`. If you use one `runST` per function, you can't have any reference persist across function calls. Even if you don't need that, making each function call allocate its mutable state on entry only to deallocate it on exit (as in your option 2) looks pointless. I would just pass a `STRef s State` around, and mutate the state through that.

There might be other aspects to consider, though. If a function performs many mutations inside, option 2 might still be OK, since the extra cost of entering/leaving would be negligible.

(I probably don't completely understand your option 3. Isn't it option 1, essentially?)

Comment: Thank you, this was my initial thought although I was suspicious because I figured state monads are supposed to eliminate explicit state passing everywhere, so I thought maybe I'm missing something.  I suppose that `ST s` isn't really a traditional state monad though.

Comment: @user12043137 Indeed it is not. It is most often used when we want to have many references around, instead of just one as in your case. I guess you could use `ReaderT (STRef s State) (ST s) a` as a monad which implicitly gives you read access to the state pointer (hence read/write access to the state). One could even make this into a `MonadState`-class type, using a wrapper. I wonder if this already exists in the libraries somewhere. Note that one should also benchmark this -- it could be slower than the basic state monad for simple state types.